# Deleting and immediately creating node in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var username="aashiquemd2212";
var myvar="14ca120";
var assmtEid=11;
function saveDB(newid)
{
    ref2 = database.ref(username+'/course/'+myvar+'/ExerciseTable/'+assmtEid+'/');
    ref2.remove();

    refe = database.ref(username+'/course/'+myvar+'/ExerciseTable');
    refe.child(assmtEid).set({
    Exid: assmtEid,
    Ename: displayname,
    Etotal: "20"
    });
    var tb=document.getElementsByClassName("tbody")[0];
    var len=tb.rows.length;
    for(var l=0;l<len;l++)
    {
        tno=l+1;
        tnam=tb.rows[l].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].value;
        tmark=tb.rows[l].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].value;
        console.log("**"+tno+"**"+tnam+"**"+tmark+"**");
        ref2.child(tno).set({
        cid:tno,
        cname:tnam,
        ctotal:tmark
        });// criteria save
         var kn=document.getElementsByClassName("tide")[0].rows.length;

         for(var lent=0;lent<kn;lent++)
         {
             mtd1=lent+1;
             mtd2=document.getElementsByClassName("tide")[l].rows[lent].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].value;
             mtd3=document.getElementsByClassName("tide")[l].rows[lent].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].value;
            console.log("--"+mtd1+"--"+mtd2+"--"+mtd3+"--");
             ref2.child(tno+"/"+mtd1+"/").set({
             did:mtd1,
             dname:mtd2,
             dmark:mtd3
             });// descriptive save

         }
         console.log("#####################");
    }

}
```

Here I am trying to delete a node and again immediately create the same node with updated elements. But when I am trying to delete and create the same node I cause some error for me. This is the image when I retrieve from the firebase DB.
[image: Before updating the DB]
[image: Firebase DB]
When I try to edit the contents I give me such like output with some error. I am changing the value **hello** to **hi**.[image: Here is the error]
[image: Extra elements are added in the firebase database]

Comment: May I ask: Why are you deleting and creating a new one instead of simply updating the existing one? And it would be nice if you could post the HTML file so we can see how many rows your tbody has